# Getting 'error reading input file' and 'bad magic number' when I try to decrypt an aes-128-cbc encrypted file

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, cbc-mode

I've been given an aes-128-cbc encrypted file to decrypt. When I run the `openssl` command, it keeps giving me an error saying 'error reading input file'

This is my command:

`openssl enc -in "$ciphertext_file" -d  -aes-128-cbc -md md5 -pass pass:"$password" -pbkdf2`

(It's part of a bash script)

If I add the -a flag, it gives me the 'bad magic number' error.

When I made my own encrypted file and decrypted it using the same command, it worked. I included the -a flag in both commands for this.

So, my theory is that the file given to me isn't base64 encoded and that's why I'm getting the error. If that's the case how can I decode it?

Comment: Show the code that encrypts the file. If you want to know how to decrypt something you have to know how it was encrypted. Otherwise you're just guessing.

Comment: It's a part of my uni coursework, I was just told it is encrypted using aes-128-cbc and nothing else (''The plaintext was encrypted using 128-bit AES with CBC mode using a single openssl enc command with no salting used, and using a password"). I'm supposed to find the password using a dictionary file they've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Given your description:

> The plaintext was encrypted using 128-bit AES with CBC mode using a single openssl enc command with no salting used, and using a password

First, you've added `-md md5`. Nothing the above description suggests that this uses MD5 hashing, so why did you add that? Unless there is more instruction, remove that. (If you've copied this line from somewhere, you can't do that without checking each parameter and making sure you know what it's for. Encryption algorithms are extremely precise.) Similarly, you've added `-pbkdf2`. Why? Do not add random options.

The instructions also say that no salting was used. Salting is the default. You must pass `-nosalt` to disable it.

If you're taking a class that includes cryptographic tools, you absolutely must read the documentation for those tools, in this case, the [openssl-enc man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html). You cannot copy random things you find online. You cannot ask ChatGPT. You have to read the docs and know why each parameter is there and what  it is doing. When you misuse cryptographic tools you do not get useful errors generally, and you do not get "something close" that you can iterate on. It is either perfect, or completely wrong, so you have to read the docs.

---

> So, my theory is that the file given to me isn't base64 encoded and that's why I'm getting the error. If that's the case how can I decode it?

The `-a` parameter requires that the input be in Base64. If it isn't (you can look and see), and your instructions don't give any suggestion that it is, then you should not add `-a`.

> The plaintext was encrypted using 128-bit AES with CBC mode using a single openssl enc command with no salting used, and using a password

If these instructions you've written here are the exact, entire instructions, then they describe the following encryption:

- "encrypted" -> enc
- "The plaintext" -> -in *file*
- "using 128-bit AES with CBC mode" -> -aes-128-cbc
- "with no salting used" -> -nosalt
- "using a password" -> -pass pass:*password*

```
openssl enc -in "$ciphertext_file" -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -pass pass:"$password"
```

And the decryption would be the same, adding `-d`.

Comment: This was the command i used orginally:
openssl enc -in "$ciphertext_file" -d -a -aes-128-cbc  -pass pass:"$password"  -nosalt
And this is the error I got:
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
80DB357F347F0000:error:1C80006B:Provider routines:ossl_cipher_generic_block_final:wrong final block length:../providers/implementations/ciphers/ciphercommon.c:429:
I added some of the 'random' flags based on similar questions I saw on stack, just to see if it helps. Also I added pbkdf2 based on this error.